# use onActivityResult instead of startActivityFOrResult

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

```
private void toggleScreenShare(View v) {
    ToggleButton toggleButton=(ToggleButton)  v;
    if(toggleButton.isChecked()){
        initRecorder();
        recordScreen();
        
    }
    else {
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mMediaRecorder.reset();
        stopRecordScreen();

        mVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(mVideoUrl));
        mVideoView.start();
    }
}

private void recordScreen() {
    if(mediaProjection==null){
       ** startActivityForResult(mMediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(),REQUEST_CODE);**
        
        return;
    }

    mVirtualDisplay=createVirtualDisplay();
    mMediaRecorder.start();
}
```

This is my code I want to use  onActivityResult in bold line because StartActivityFOrResult is deprecated ,Can anyone help me how to write this

I'm try many times and want the code

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code, will get you the result of the intent.

```
/**
 * In your activity
 * this will get you the result from the other intent.
 * I do not know, what exactly you are exactly doing there.
 * So you no longer need technically the request code.
 */
private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> yourLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
        Intent intentData = result.getData();

        if (intentData == null) return;

        intentData.getBooleanExtra("BOOLEAN", false);
    }
});
```

This part of the code will call your launcher with your wanted intent.

```
yourLauncher.launch(mMediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent());
```

Hopefully this simple example enlightens the method.